# How to [join on] [where] in r data.tables

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way to combine the join on and subset functionality in data.table? Say I have the following table:

```
dt = data.table(itemID = c(1,1,2,2),bucketID = c(1,2,2,3),value = 1:4)
```

I want to set the value to zero for the lowest bucket of each item. My thought was to run:

```
ends = dt[,.(min = min(bucketID)),itemID]
dt[ends,on="itemID",bucketID==min,value:=0]
```

i.e. join the tables, find where the two rows are identical, then update the value column. But this doesn't work. I can get the right results with:

```
ends = dt[,.(min = min(bucketID)),itemID]
dt = dt[ends,on="itemID"][bucketID==min,value:=0][,c(-4)]
```

However, this seems a bit circuitous. Is there a better way to combine join and where?

Comment: perhapse `dt[
 ends
 , on = c("itemID", bucketID = "min")
 , value := 0
]` ?

Comment: Or maybe avoid a join altogether - `dt[dt[, bucketID == min(bucketID), by=itemID]$V1, value := 0]`

Comment: @thelatemail would be an interesting benchmark on larger data

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on your join approach, you can join by both the `itemID` and the `min` values

```
dt[
    ends
    , on = c("itemID", bucketID = "min")
    , value := 0
]

dt
#    itemID bucketID value
# 1:      1        1     0
# 2:      1        2     2
# 3:      2        2     0
# 4:      2        3     4
```

Comment: The join seems quite a bit faster than my suggestion above from a quick test on `dt2 <- data.table(itemID=rep(1:1e6,each=2), bucketID=rep(1:1e6, 2), value=1:1e6)`

Comment: @thelatemail - does that include the `ends` step? I'm getting different results

Comment: `system.time(dt2[ dt2[,.(min = min(bucketID)),itemID], on = c("itemID", bucketID = "min") , value := 0 ])` vs `system.time(dt2[dt2[, bucketID == min(bucketID), by=itemID]$V1, value := 0])` seems to show the join about 4-5 times quicker.

Comment: @thelatemail - intersting: I was using `dt3 <- data.table(itemID = sample(1:100, size = 1e7, replace = T), 
         bucketID = sample(1:100, size = 1e7, replace = T),
         value = sample(1:100, size = 1e7, replace = T))`

Comment: if the order is set at the start `setorder(dt3, itemID, bucketID)`, then my method is quicker, but if it's random, yours is